# Correct form of active voice

Tags: passive-voice

The class at pinnacle will have been begun by the time we get there.

a) they will have begun the class at pinnacle by the time we get there.
b) By the time we get there the class at pinnacle will have begun.

Which one is correct in active voice? My teacher say 2) have wrong beginning , but i dont think so. Please clarify. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question, because there is no indirect speech in any of your examples. All your examples are perfectly good, except that "been begun" is very unusual unless the agent ("by X") is expressed: we normally use the [unaccusative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb) (intransitive) "begin" as in your b).

Comment: It should be"By the time we get there, the class at pinnacle will have begun."

Comment: @ram Are you sure you meant to say "indirect speech"? Perhaps this is a passive voice exercise and you were asked to turn the sentence into the active (anyway, let me tell you the original in the passive is hardly idiomatic).

Answer (score -1):

I'd say that they are both active voice.

In (a), the subject is "They" and the the active, transitive verb is "will have begun".

In (b), the subject is "the class" and the active, intransitive verb is "begun"

(btw: I don't know what "pinnacle" means here. If it is a proper noun it should be capitalized; otherwise it should be "the pinnacle")